# C++14 ignore return type in interface getter but specify it in implementation

Tags: c++, c++14, virtual, return-type

I have three classes of objects:

- class Foo: has a mesh, and I need to get that mesh;
- class Bar: is a Foo, but has some further capabilities which Foo doesn't have;
- class Baz: is a Foo, but has another completely independent set of capabilities which neither Foo nor Bar have.

All three classes need to have a way to give me their mesh which, however, can be implemented in many ways, of which I need (at the moment I can't see another way) to use at least 2 different ones, which are MeshTypeA and MeshTypeB.

I would like to have a common interface for different implementations of the same concept (getMesh), however, I can't use auto in a virtual method. I'm lacking the facility to make the code have sense. I would like to have:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  virtual ~Foo() = 0;
  virtual auto getMesh() const = 0;  // doesn't compile
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
  virtual ~Bar() = 0;
  virtual auto getMesh() const = 0;  // doesn't compile
  // other virtual methods
};

class ConcreteFooWhichUsesA : public Foo
{
public:
  ConcreteFooWhichUsesA();
  ~ConcreteFooWhichUsesA();
  auto getMesh() const override {return mesh_;};

private:
  MeshTypeA mesh_;
};

class ConcreteBarWhichUsesB : public Bar
{
public:
  ConcreteBarWhichUsesB();
  ~ConcreteBarWhichUsesB();
  auto getMesh() const override {return mesh_;};
  // other implementations of virtual methods

private:
  MeshTypeB mesh_;
};
```

MeshTypeA and MeshTypeB are not exclusive to Foo, Bar, or Baz, which is to say all three could have both types of mesh. However I really don't care for which MeshType I get when I later use it.

Do I need to wrap MeshTypeA and MeshTypeB in my own MeshType? Is it a matter of templating the MeshType? I believe there is a way, however related questions aren't helping or I can't formulate my question in a meaningful enough way.

I have also found [this](https://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-auto-decltype-return-value-after-function.html) where the author uses a Builder class and decltype, but I don't have such a class. Maybe that would be it? Do I need a MeshLoader sort of class as an indirection level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your MeshTypes all have a common (abstract) base class, then you can just return (a pointer or reference to) that in the virtual function defintions, and the derived classes can then return their concrete mesh types, and all will be well.  If you have code that can work on any mesh type, it is going to need that abstract base anyways.

If your MeshTypes do not all have a common base class, why even have a getMesh method in Foo at all?  Remove it and give each of the concrete classes it's own getMesh method that doesn't override (and has nothing in particular to do with the meshes in any other concrete class).

Comment: They do not have a common base class, the client wraps them in another object and does its thing.

Comment: If you're in a function that just has a `Foo *` (it doesn't know which concrete Foo it is) can it expect to call `getMesh` to get a mesh?  If so, that mesh *is* the common abstract base class of all the mesh types.  If not, there's no need to have `getMesh` as a method of `Foo`

Comment: With your edit, are you saying I should take getMesh out of the interface? Why would I not want to have a client function that takes a `Foo` and gets its mesh the same way as any other `Foo`.

After your suggestion, I was thinking I could abstract out a base class MyMesh to give to all three, like you suggest in your answer. They do not have it, but I can write it, right? Any `Foo` should have a mesh, therefore if I make it an abstraction and then implement it with either derived type I should be fine and `all will be well`.

Comment: The types were a conversion away from a common base class, conversion which I had not seen previously.

Answer (score 2):

A function's return type is part of its interface. You can't just change it willy-nilly. More specifically, you cannot have a base class virtual method return one thing while an overridden version returns another. OK, you *can*, but only if the derived version's return type is convertible to the base class return type (in which case, calling through the base class function will perform said conversion on the overriding method's return type).

C++ is a statically typed language; the compiler *must* know what an expression evaluates to at compile time. Since polymorphic inheritance is a runtime property (that is, the compiler is not guaranteed to be able to know which override will be called through a base class pointer/reference), you cannot have polymorphic inheritance change compile-time constructs, like the type of a function call expression. If you call a virtual method of a base class instance, the compiler will expect this expression to evaluate to what that base class's method returns.

Remember: the point of polymorphic inheritance is that you can write code that doesn't know about the derived classes and have it still work with them. What you're trying to do violates that.

Comment: This seemed already clear to me, that's why I had "doesn't compile" in the comments, maybe I should have been more explicit with an "of course it doesn't compile". The issue, I guess, is with `the compiler must know what an expression evaluates to at compile time` because it already does: once I get in the implementation of ConcreteFooWhichUsesA or ConcreteBarWhichUsesB the implementation itself specifies which MeshType I'm using.

Comment: @LaboratorioCobotica: But users of `Foo` *do not* know which `MeshType` you're using. Consider `void func(Foo &f) {auto thing = f.getMesh();}`. What is the type of `thing`? In C++, that must have a answer single answer, which shall be the same for all users of `Foo`. And therefore, that answer can *only depend* on the definition of `Foo`. Not of the definition of anything derived from it.

Comment: `Foo` is an abstract class, it can't be instantiated. I would call `func(concreteFoo);` and that concreteFoo will need to have a defined MeshType

Comment: @LaboratorioCobotica: Then why do you have a base class at all? The *whole point* of a polymorphic base class is that you pass pointers/references to the base class interface to other classes. If you're only ever going to pass `concreteFoo` around, and nobody ever takes a `Foo` directly, then `Foo` doesn't need to exist at all. Remember the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle); if you're not following it, then you're not really using polymorphism and you don't need a base class.

Comment: Aren't we saying the exact same thing? I am receiving, inside `func`, a `Foo`, yet passing it a `concreteFoo` exactly because I know I can accept any `Foo` inside `func` because they all give me some type of mesh

Comment: To concretize the LSP: given phi = having a mesh, object `foo` of class `Foo`, `bar` of class `Bar` and `baz` of class `Baz` all have the property phi. They all are, effectively, `Foo`s, but the other kinds have other sets of properties which `Foo`s don't have

Comment: @LaboratorioCobotica: "*Aren't we saying the exact same thing?*" No, we aren't, because in your world "having a mesh" means "a function that returns... something that I consider to be a mesh." While in C++ world, "having a mesh" means "a function that returns the mesh type defined by `Foo::getMesh()`". If your derived class implementations of `getMesh` don't deal in the mesh type defined by the base class `getMesh`, then they're not substitutable via runtime polymorphism in C++. C++ doesn't deal in "some type of mesh"; it deals in actual types.

Comment: After a couple hours I realized what you say is 100% correct and I was basically trying to do return type overload, which is not feasible, of course.